# create docker image for azure devops build agent unable to locate package for dotnet-sdk-7.0

Tags: docker, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-container-apps

I'm trying to follow the guidance from [this blog post](https://moimhossain.com/2022/11/08/self-hosted-azure-devops-pool-on-azure-container-apps/)

I need the docker image to have the dotnet sdk installed. It's also got to run in Azure Container Apps, which has a limitation that is can't have root access.

My Dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

LABEL Author="Moim Hossain"
LABEL Email="moimhossain@gmail.com"
LABEL GitHub="https://github.com/moimhossain"
LABEL BaseImage="ubuntu:20.04"
 
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get upgrade -y && useradd -m agentuser
 
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y -qq --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https \
    apt-utils \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    git \
    iputils-ping \
    jq \
    lsb-release \
    software-properties-common
 
RUN curl -sL https://aka.ms/InstallAzureCLIDeb | bash
 
# Can be 'linux-x64', 'linux-arm64', 'linux-arm', 'rhel.6-x64'.
ENV TARGETARCH=linux-x64
 
WORKDIR /azp
RUN chown -R agentuser:agentuser /azp
RUN chmod 755 /azp

# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    apt-transport-https \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    software-properties-common

# Install .NET Core SDK
RUN wget https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/20.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb -O packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0
 
COPY ./start.sh .
RUN chmod +x start.sh
# All subsequent commands run under this user
USER agentuser
 
ENTRYPOINT [ "./start.sh", "--once" ]
```

When I run this on my mac (m1 cpu), it seems to work fine until it gets to the point where it's trying to add dotnet. This is the end of the output:

```
13 1.272 Get:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/ubuntu/20.04/prod focal/main all Packages [2521 B]
#13 1.298 Fetched 504 kB in 1s (952 kB/s)
#13 1.298 Reading package lists...
#13 1.912 Reading package lists...
#13 2.361 Building dependency tree...
#13 2.446 Reading state information...
#13 2.477 E: Unable to locate package dotnet-sdk-7.0
#13 2.477 E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'dotnet-sdk-7.0'
#13 2.477 E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'dotnet-sdk-7.0'
```

I suspect the problem relates to permission of the user running the command *apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0*?

Comment: Why you don't simply start from a .NET SDK image? Like `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0` instead of installing it manually?

Comment: I've answered with the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify your custom image creation process you can start directly from the images provided out of the box by Microsoft with the already installed SDK: `mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0`.

On Docker Hub you can find all the [Microsoft .NET ready to use images](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-dotnet) with runtimes and SDK.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it got me over that hurdle but now I have another! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76694715/azure-devops-agent-running-in-container